# Is it possible to reboot Android Automotive OS to fastboot/recovery using physical keyboard?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, automotive-head-unit

I have a media-system module occasionally locked in OTA mode. It does not respond on any buttons pressed or screens tapped - but it still works: adb port works (but there is no trusted connection so I cannot manually reboot it by console), and if someone has a call to my SIM, it goes well by handsfree system.
I have the possibility to plug in a physical keyboard. It worked when the system was fine.

Does automotive have any special commands or combinations for rebooting into recovery/fastboot/whatever? I need to unbrick it :(

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Could you [edit] and clarify whether it's running Android OS or Android Auto?